# Setting default image position and wrapping in MS Word 2010 Templates

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Long story short: I am building a custom Word template to match a new style guide. Somewhere along the line insert images into the template has gone really wrong - the default is set as inline as text which means that the image ends up being one line high.

Obviously users can change this each time they insert a picture, however that is not ideal. Can somebody point me in the direct of making an image default position that isn't 'inline with text'?

Example:

[image: 1]

Comment: What are you changing it to, to get the desired result?

Comment: Technie007 might be on to something here. Could you set the default line height to "at least" under paragraph settings? This way you would not have to change the default position of inserted images.

Comment: So it goes in as 'In line with text', adjusting to anything else such as 'Square' gets it to where I want it to be. (sorry for the delayed response; I managed to break my collar bone over the weekend).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurred because the line spacing in the paragraph settings was set to 'Exact'. The remedy to this was to set the line spacing to 'at least'.